# Evaluate $\int_{|z|=1} z^2 d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\mathbb{T} = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1\}$, $\phi:[0,1] \to \mathbb{T}$ be defined by $\phi(t) = e^{2 \pi i t}$, $m$ be the Lebesgue measure, and let $\mu(E) = m(\phi^{-1}(E))$. Find $$\int_{\mathbb{T}} z^2 d\mu$$

---

I think that I should do the following: 
$$\int_{\mathbb{T}}z^2 d(m \circ \phi^{-1}) = \int_{\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{T})} (\phi(t))^2 dm = \int_0^1 e^{4\pi i t} dm = 0$$
But I'm worried I've oversimplified something here. Is this all I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is all you need.

Alternatively, note that $d\mu$ is invariant under the rotation
$z\mapsto iz$, so that
$$\int_T z^2\,d\mu=\int_T (iz)^2\,d\mu$$
etc.